# Researching Computer Security, where to start

Tags: security

How does information leaves your own personal computer with Windows 10 operating system? Beside from your known emails.
I know it is broad subject but where do you start.

Comment: I would start with seeking advice in proper community like [InfoSec](https://security.stackexchange.com/). You question will be deleted here as off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I did not even know InfoSec existed. Delete away.

Comment: If you go into a command line and run `netstat -a`, it shows you every communication port that is in use on your machine. If the "Foreign Address" is not your computer then that indicates something external to your computer (likely on the internet) has a connection to your computer. Any of these ports could be leaking "information". But is it information you care about? Do you care if MS is collecting "performance information" from your laptop? That's just one way information leaves.

Comment: Another way is that you could literally be typing things into a web form. It might help to more specifically classify what you are looking for. If you exclude everything that you knowingly enter into a webform and also exclude everything that is mentioned in some kind of EULA then you might start finding some areas of interest.

Answer (score 0):

For researching computer security, you may need to start from basics of interdevice communication and data transfer. It should include computer hardware, communication protocols - networking and broader information security topics. You can start with free, open sources like Youtube etc to play and learn basics. Later on, you will dive into deeper topics if you get interested enough.

However, if you get into cybersecurity related job, you may need to start fom feeder jobs like IT helpdesk, software engineer, IT adminstrator which will provide you core knowledge and skills.